# output image in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image and a text area.

I want to ouput the image in the text area using Jquery. However when I try, it just outputs the html instead of the image, how can I output the image to the text area:

```
var output = '';
output += '<img src="http://aux.iconpedia.net/uploads/286412642.png" />';
$('#textarea').html(output);​
```

I have set up a jsfiddle in order to demonstrate the scenario and to illustrate what I have tried.

http://jsfiddle.net/DpeU7/

I know its called a *text*area for a reason, but am looking for a way to do this.

Comment: How do you think an image can be inside of a **TEXT** area??? You should put images inside of `<div>`s and `<span>`s not inside `<textarea>`

Comment: Hint: it's called _textarea_ for a reason. What you _can_ do is overlay an image over a textarea, if that is what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `div` with `contentEditable="true"` instead of `textarea`.

Look at [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bpNFV/).

Comment: This does seem to be the best option for what OP is trying to accomplish. Especially given its cross-browser compatibility: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Content_Editable

Comment: If OP just wanted output, a _non_-`contentEditable` `div` would work just as well.

Comment: @Amadan I believe, that if OP has `1K` rating, then using `div` instead of `textarea` would be straightforward for him.If he mentioned `textarea`, then he wanted something 'editable'.

Answer (score 4):

You can not output an image into a text area. If you want to do that, you would need to use something like [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

Comment: Just note, that it's not `<textarea>` but CSS that makes it look like a textarea.